# vim ctags, two same entries, won't jump to definition directly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, vim, ctags

I use `ctags -R .` to generate tags,

if I try `ctrl ]` on some function, I always get two same entries

```
 # pri kind tag                    file
  1 F   f    accept_the_connection  src/connection.c
               int accept_the_connection(connection *conn)
  2 F   f    accept_the_connection  src/connection.c
               int accept_the_connection(connection *conn)
Type number and <Enter> (empty cancels):
```

I have to type 1 or 2 to jump to the definition.

How to make VIM jump directly?

UPDATE 1:

It seems to be a problem of my environment

So I have a Mac host with VirtualBox installed, and I have a CentOS guest.
I develop in the CentOS env.

And I created a shared folder between Mac and CentOS:

```
[Mac]/Users/sato/Dropbox/projects/asdf => [Centos] /home/sato/asdf
```

and src/connection.c is in /home/sato/asdf

if I copy asdf to /home/sato/fdsa then `ctrl ]` in vim works

Comment: Do you have several `.ctags` files? Like one in the project directory and one in your `$HOME` directory? Or several `tags` and `TAGS` files in your project?

Comment: @romainl there's only one `tags` file generated by `ctags -R .` in this project. If I delete this tags file, `ctrl+]` won't work.

Comment: OK for the `tags` file. But what about the `.ctags` file?

Comment: `.ctags` does not exist either

Comment: Well you clearly have duplicate entries in your `tags` file and that's what causing this "issue". Find the root cause, fix it, and the issue will disappear.

Comment: I just use `ctags -R .` to generate tags file, and I grep accept_the_connection in it, there's only one entry.

Comment: Where do you execute that command? At the root of the project? Also, from `$HOME`, you could try `$ find . -name 'tags' | grep -v .git` to see if you have more than one `tags` file in the upward search path. Also, see if the output of `:echo tagfiles()` gives you a list with more than one item.

Comment: FWIW, what you see is very typical sign of using several `tags` file. In [these pics](http://imgur.com/a/99Yws) I have three `tags` files.

Comment: yes, i ran the command at the root of the project. and `find` gives me  exact this tags file, also i tried `find TAGS`, no TAGS file. `:echo tagfiles` gives me `['tags', 'TAGS']`

Comment: `['tags', 'TAGS']` means you have 2 `tags` files (`tags` and `TAGS`) and Vim is looking for tags in those two files. `$ ctags -R .` creates a `tags` file by default so the extraneous file is `TAGS`. Removing it will almost certainly fix your problem. But if you have a `TAGS` file and you didn't explicitly create it you should probably not remove it as it is part of the project. If that's the case, I'd suggest changing your command to `$ ctags -R -f TAGS .`.

Comment: @romainl there's no TAGS file. I have updated the post, seems something to do with the env

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can supply a *count* to the command, i.e. `1<C-]>`, but that's only a workaround.

The right way to fix this is to avoid having two identical entries in the tags database. From your output, it's impossible to tell what caused this. I have encountered this in the past when there were backup files (which had a different file extension), or if I ran the `ctags` on a directory too high up in the hierarchy, so different versions of the same library were included.